# Triangulation of reduced suspension

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request

I am searching for a source in which I can find a proof of the following result:

Is $X$ an simplicial complex, then the reduced suspension (double cone with identification of $[0,1]× x_0$ ) is a simplicial complex too.

Comment: What do you mean by *is* a simplicial complex? In particular, think of the case $X = [0,1]$.